# React: make a JSON object reactive, making a property inside a JSON object reactive, updating div on change

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks

Fiddle: https://codesandbox.io/s/modern-tree-27z3q2?file=/src/App.js

I have very simple code that displays all elements in an array `animals` (which has only one JSON object: `{'name': 'A', 'kind': 'dog'}`.

[image]

When a button is clicked the `name` gets changed to `Better Name` value. However the displayed data doesn't get updated.

**App.js**:

```
import "./styles.css";
import React, { useEffect, useState } from "react";

export default function App() {
  let [animals, setAnimals] = useState([]);

  useEffect(() => {
    let temp = [];

    temp.push({ name: "A", kind: "dog" });

    setAnimals(temp);
  }, []);

  async function changeAnimalName(animal) {
    animal.name = "Better Name";

    alert(JSON.stringify(animals[0]));
  }

  return (
    <div className="App">
      {animals.map((animal) => (
        <div>
          <b>{animal.name}</b> is a <b>{animal.kind}</b>
          <div
            style={{
              marginTop: "1em",
              backgroundColor: "green",
              padding: "1em",
              borderRadius: "2em"
            }}
            onClick={() => {
              changeAnimalName(animal);
            }}
          >
            Change Name
          </div>
        </div>
      ))}
    </div>
  );
}
```

After I click the `Change Name` button, I get this alert message:

[image]

So the `name` of the first JSON object in the `animals` array was changed, however the page still displays:

[image]

I'm coming from `Vue` where the update would be automatic. I see that in react the `useState` is used to manage reactivity, however I'm unsure how to do that for `JSON` objects that already exist.

Comment: you cant update state like this; you have to call `setAnimals` whenever you want to change the state of animals

Comment: `animals` is only a snapshot of what the state looks like, it isn't reactive and you can't mutate it

Comment: did you have a chance to review my answer below?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As I mentioned in my comments, you cannot update state that way; `animals` is just a snapshot of what the state looks like and it cannot be mutated.

The `useState` Hook provides two things:

- A state variable to retain the data between renders.
- A state setter function to update the variable and trigger React to render the component again.

### Solution

Working code: https://codesandbox.io/s/modest-sun-k7suvt?file=/src/App.js

```js
import "./styles.css";
import React, { useEffect, useState } from "react";

export default function App() {
  let [animals, setAnimals] = useState([]);

  useEffect(() => {
    let temp = [];

    temp.push({ name: "A", kind: "dog" });

    setAnimals(temp);
  }, []);

  async function changeAnimalName(index) {
    setAnimals((animalsArr) => {
      return animalsArr.map((animal, i) => {
        if (index === i) {
          animal.name = "Better Name";
        }

        return animal;
      });
    });
  }

  return (
    <div className="App">
      {animals.map((animal, i) => (
        <div>
          <b>{animal.name}</b> is a <b>{animal.kind}</b>
          <div
            style={{
              marginTop: "1em",
              backgroundColor: "green",
              padding: "1em",
              borderRadius: "2em"
            }}
            onClick={() => {
              changeAnimalName(i);
            }}
          >
            Change Name
          </div>
        </div>
      ))}
    </div>
  );
}
```

### Explanation

I'm sending the index of the animal I want to mutate; typically, this should be a unique ID but in this simple sample, this should work just fine.

Then, I update the state:

```js
setAnimals((animalsArr) => {
  return animalsArr.map((animal, i) => {
    if (index === i) {
      animal.name = "Better Name";
    }

    return animal;
  });
});
```

So I find the correct animal based on the index, and make that change inside `setAnimals`. Keep in mind, you must make a call to `setAnimals` whenever you want to update `animals` state

### Further Reading

- https://react.dev/learn/state-a-components-memory

Comment: What if some element in the `animals` list was changed (elements were displayed in a for loop, and on click a certain element gets its data updated), and I do something like `setAnimals(animals)`? Would it work in React? I tried in my bigger project, but for some reason it doesn't work

Comment: so `animalsArr` is an example of how you make sure you get the most recent data; but basically, `setAnimals` gets passed an array that contains the latest state snapshot. What you return from that function is what the state is then updated to